# Probability of fulfilling an order using specific number of packages

Tags: probability

Generic problem:

Given an order for **X** unique units, what is the probability of being able to fill that entire order using **Y** packages (or locations), if the probability of finding each unique unit in each location is **Z** percent and the total number of possible locations to choose from is **W**.

Real example:

Given an order for 10 unique items, what is the probability of being able to source the order from exactly 2 stores if the probability of having an item is 10% for each item at each store and the number of stores to choose from is 100.

Answer (score 0):

Just take it one step at a time.

Let $F_{i,j}$ be the event that unit-$i$ is found in store-$j$.  The probability of finding a particular unit in a particular store, is:

$$\Pr(F_{i,j})=Z$$

The probability of *not* finding a particular unit in a particular store is :

$$\Pr(F_{i,j}^\complement)~=~$$

The probability of *not* finding a particular unit when looking in $Y$ stores is :

$$\Pr(\bigcap\limits_{j=1}^Y F_{i,j}^\complement) ~=~$$

The probability of actually finding a particular item when looking in those stores is :

$$\Pr(\bigcup_{j=1}^Y F_{i,j})~=~$$

The probability of finding *all* the items for the order in those stores is :

$$\Pr(\bigcap_{i=1}^X\bigcup_{j=1}^Y F_{i,j}) ~=~$$

$\lozenge$

---

**Remark:** The fact that there are $W$ locations from which to choose the $Y$ is irrelevant when its been asserted that there is a constant success rate, $Z$, of finding a unique unit in each store.  (However, this model is questionable.)